# How to know if a sine wave must be described as a sine function or as a complex exponential?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, acoustics

In problems, sine waves (electromagnetic, acoustic, ...) are often described as $\psi(\mathbf{x},t) = \psi_0\sin(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \omega t)$.

However, they sometimes need to be described as $\psi(\mathbf{x},t) = \psi_0 e^{j(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \omega t)}$.

Is there a way to guess the required description of a given problem ?

Comment: The exponential notation is introduced to make calculations easier by using the complex plane, but you are free to use whichever formulation you prefer, they are equivalent (as long as at the end of the problem you recover real function).

Comment: Usually your boundary or initial conditions play a role in designating sine, cosine or exponential as the solution (i.e., particular or general solutions)

Comment: see http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-complex-exponential-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by Lith in comments.

> The exponential notation is introduced to make calculations easier by using the complex plane, but you are free to use whichever formulation you prefer, they are equivalent (as long as at the end of the problem you recover real function).